# Plotting correlation matrices

Tags: time-series, correlation, data-visualization

I have a time series of correlation matrics (generated from a multivariate time series over time). Here I am wondering what is the best way to graphically represent the times series of corr matrices? Should I just extract individual pair and plot time series individually? What is the best practice?

Comment: Hah, if you have a nice long time series, I would create a series of heatmaps and create an animation :-)

Comment: Bogaso, I notice you haven't yet accepted any answers to questions you have asked. You can help yourself, future users, and this site as a whole, by following the guidance in the faq: "As you see new answers to your question, vote up the helpful ones by clicking the upward pointing arrow to the left of the answer. ... When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer."

Comment: Do you actually mean that you have a matrix of the pairwise correlations of a number (how many) of time series? Currently reads "a time series of correlation matrics" which I don't think is what you mean - I don't think you actually have a time series of correlations - or do you?

Comment: @Peter Ellis My time series has 10 variables. Therefore I have 250 historical CORR matrices each with 10X10 dimension. Thanks,

Comment: I still only make that one matrix of 10 x 10 correlations, based on 250 observations per variable (not 250 10 x 10 correlation matrices).  I must be misunderstanding something?

Comment: OK, I finally worked it out, you have 10 variables, an n observations on each of those variables, taken at 250 points of time.  What I'd missed was that each point of time was an n x rectangle of data

Comment: There is a CRAN package for plotting correlation matrices:   `corrplot`   see http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/visualize-correlation-matrix-using-correlogram